# Does GWT have its own notion of classpath?

Tags: gwt, classpath, java

Does the GWT compiler have a notion of its own "classpath" that is separate from the normal compile-time classpath? Does a GWT app (and its internal workings) have the notion of its own classpath that is separate from the normal JRE runtime classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT has the notion of modules. Each module does declare what packages are in its source path. Modules can extend other modules. Every Class the GWT compiles has to be in the source path of one module your main module extends from.

The notion of sourcepath combined with modules builds some kind of separate classpath just for the GWT Compiler. But it has nothing to do with the java classpath.

Comment: Er well, the source path actually is a subset of the classpath; GWT loads everything out the classpath, it doesn't look elsewhere.

Comment: you are right Thomas, I just wanted to emphasize that just because something is on the classpath gwt will not load it. It has to be in a modules source path.