# GWT Modules and Inheritance

Tags: java, gwt, inheritance, module, dependencies

What's with all the "inherit" stuff in module descriptor:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
```

...inherit what from what? Why is this necessary? This *feels* a lot like the *importing* of a `User` class, not *inheriting* from it? I guess I'm just confused as to why modules "inherit" instead of "import", seeing that its more of a dependency thing.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330611/does-gwt-have-its-own-notion-of-classpath

Comment: Thanks @DanielKurka (+1) - so is `com.google.gwt.user.User` a module or a specific class? If its an entire module, then I "get it", because like you say in that answer, modules can extend other modules (thus inheritance makes sense). But if `User` is just a class, then it still doesn't make sense, because my module isn't *inheriting* anything from a `User`; it's *using* a `User`, and therefore should be *importing* it, yes? Thanks again!

Comment: com.google.gwt.user.User actually means the gwt.xml file at com.google.gwt.user.User, so its a module...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are right in that "import" or "include" would make more sense than "inherit".

As you know you could have both server and client code into the same project or even shared classes. It's up to you to organize the java code in any way you want, but the module XML is needed for GWT to find the classes that would need to be translated into javascript. In any case you are not importing classes here, but other modules, which can include one or more code folders/packages.